# How do I set the format of the rest of an XML file?

Tags: xml, perl, format, twig

I have an XML file and use following code to parse it:

```
open( $filehandle, "+<$path") or die "cannot open out file out_file:$!";
my $roots = { tag1 => 1 };
my $handlers = { 'tag0/tag1' => $tweak_server,
               };
my $twig = new XML::Twig(TwigRoots                => $roots,
                         TwigHandlers             => $handlers,
                         pretty_print             => 'indented',
                         twig_print_outside_roots => \*$filehandle
                        );
$twig->parsefile($path);
$twig->flush($filehandle, pretty_print => 'indented');
close $filehandle;
```

In the output, the format of all tag1 parts are good. They are just in their original format, but the rest part of the file are not well-formatted. There are some empty lines between tags and what's more, the text content inside an element is added some empty lines which shouldn't be there.

Is there a way to parse the rest of the XML file into their original format?

Answer (score 0):

Is your XML valid (it's not HTML, is it?!)? Some example input/output XML would be really helpful.

Anyway, after playing with XML::Twig I can safely say it won't strip out empty lines. However you could work around that by writing your own reading function that returns the XML without extra newlines.

```
sub readxml {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    local $/;
    my $xml = <$fh>;
    $xml =~ s/\n+/\n/g;
    return $xml;
}

#
$twig->parse(readxml($filehandle));
```

Next, I don't think twig will pretty print content that goes through 'twig_print_outside_roots'. However you could either remove the 'TwigRoots' or add extra handlers to get the remaining content in (or use a '_default_' handler) - that way it will get pretty print treatment like all the other nodes.